# Optimal Face-Detection Picture/Schematic

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, face-detection, image-recognition

I have a face-detection-algorithm that works great and fast (iOS' default CIDetector) when I use it to detect real human faces.
Now I want to detect a test-image I put on a screen somewhere in a room, so I have total control of the image-to-be-detected, the only thing I need to be very sure about is the size on the screen.

I tested it with a simple smiley painted on an HTML5 Canvas (like this: [image]
which is recognized as a face, but not as fast & often as an actual image would (like this: [image].

As you can expect it's really hard to google this, is there sort of a goto-schematic picture with really pronounced facial features that people use?

EDIT: If someone knows a good algorithm to reverse-engineer the perfect image for an existing, black-box face-detection, then this would also solve the problem ;)

Comment: analyze the trained model data and reconstruct the used features directly? or do you want to use the "features" that human visual conception mechanisms use between/in eyes and brain? ask some psychologists visual perception experts.

Comment: Yes, basically I have a trained data model that detects faces really well and now I need some sort of "perfect face". With background and all in a state so that it's most recognizable.

Comment: reconstruct the "features" that build the model ;) might not look like a face in the end, but is probably the "optimal" face that can be detected by that detector.

Comment: So how would you reconstruct them? (I have worked with image recognition frameworks, but I'm not aware of a mainstream reverse-engineering algorithm for training-images)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is really possible, but afaik for HaarClassifier the used features are explicitly given after training (e.g. in a xml file). For SVM HoG you have positive and negative weights at different locations. From my intuition it is possible, but I'm no expert in machine learning, so I might be wrong there.

Comment: Mhmm, I modified my smiley to a more detailed face, it appears the hair made a huge difference and big eyes help too. The canvas-code to draw my test-face is still only 200lines, check it out:
http://imgur.com/Op6AUt2